# Datagridview - edit selected row?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have set Datagridview .ReadOnly property to True, and then added a button column. Button column is meant for edit button when clicked, but I wish to edin only currently selected row. This is what I tried:

EDIT:

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    Me.DataGridView1.Height = 0.8 * Me.Height
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Users._USERS' table.                           You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.USERSTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Users._USERS)
    Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Arial", 7)

 End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
   MyBase.OnLoad(e)
   For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
   DataGridView1.Rows(i).ReadOnly = True
   Next
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

Dim yourColumnIndex As Int32 = 3
If e.ColumnIndex = yourColumnIndex Then

If MsgBox("Do you wish to edit records?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Edit records") = vbYes Then
 DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ReadOnly = False

End If
End If

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowLeave
     DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ReadOnly = True
End Sub


 End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working, I just changed your suggestion a little bit (DatagridView Readonly property must be set to False):

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        For Each band As DataGridViewBand In DataGridView1.Columns
            band.ReadOnly = True
        Next
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
Dim yourColumnIndex As Int32 = 3
If e.ColumnIndex = yourColumnIndex Then
   If MsgBox("Do you wish to edit record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Edit      record") = vbYes Then
   For Each band As DataGridViewBand In DataGridView1.Columns
       band.ReadOnly = False
   Next
   End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowLeave
    For Each band As DataGridViewBand In DataGridView1.Columns
        band.ReadOnly = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for all your help Lars!

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the grid's ReadOnly property to true.  After the rows are added to the grid, you would have to loop through your rows and set the ReadOnly property for each row:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnLoad(e)
  For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).ReadOnly = True
  Next
End Sub
```

Note: you can't set these properties in the form's constructor, a quirk of the DataGridView control.

Then use the RowIndex property provided by the `e` parameter:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, 
                                           e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
                                           Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
  If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ReadOnly = False
  End If
End Sub
```

Set it back to true when leaving the row:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowLeave(sender As Object,
                                   e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
                                   Handles DataGridView1.RowLeave
  DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Lars, but It's not working. I've set DatagridView control .ReadOnly to true again.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 The code I posted worked on my machine.  You would have to be more descriptive than "it's not working".

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner in vb.net, I think there might be sometinhg wrong with Overrides Sub. When form is opened, DatagridView is stiil editable (if I set property .ReadOnly to False). If set to True also same result. Do I have to put this code somewhere else, I allready have Form_Load event ?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 Put the code you have in your load event and place in the OnLoad override I provided.  Form's shouldn't listen to their own events, always use the override instead

Comment: I don't get it. code in load event is something else.... Wait, see my edited question, a full code from form.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 I see you fill a DataTable, but where are you attaching the DataTable to the grid's DataSource?  You can't set the rows to ReadOnly until *after* the grid has rows.

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Grid has rows, when form opens, all records are seen, This is Oracle DB connection, and It's working.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 Oh, it's connected through the designer then.  What does ` Me.USERSTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Users._USERS)` have to do with the question then?  How many rows does the table have when it tries to set the ReadOnly property to true?  Use a stop debugger and examine the values.  Again, the grid control has to have the ReadOnly property to false for this to work.  BTW, don't resize the grid on the resize event — just set the grid's anchor property.

Comment: I pasted all code from form2 module, just to show you everything so you might see issues, Me.USERS doesn't have anything to do with question. I'm not sure how you wanted to test how many rows does the table have when it tries to set ReadOnly property to true. And yes, Grid control's Readonly property is set to False.....Resize is because this form is opened in another form maximized (MDI client) , never tried anchoring though.

Comment: Lars, have tried again and It works but very strangely...While clicking through records somehow code starts working, but not at the beginning ?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 That's a different question.  How many rows do you have?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 I can't explain your delay since it's probably some code I can't see.  If I put 300 rows in my grid, everything is instant.

Comment: Ok, here is how code works. When form loads, records are added, and my cursor position is on first row. When I click in 1st row, Datagrid is ReadOnly False...But when I move on some other record AND THEN RETURN TO ROW 1, code starts working. And from this point, code works

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 Then clearly the foreach loop isn't working with the way you have things set up.  Try using the OnShown override instead maybe.  It would be a good day for you to learn to use the debugger, stop the code when it's running, and examine the values.  Click on the gray margin to the left of your code to put a red stop on a line then run your code.

Comment: I have tried OnShown override too, not working. Maybe something else wrong, I don't know. Yes I have to train, I'm a VBA programmer, last time I used VS was VB6, so everything is very new to me.

Comment: Lars, haven't figured out why your suggestion doesn't work for me, but I changed a little bit and now work. I'll post an answer in few minutes, check  it out.